# How to access list value in Get-EC2Instance's RunningInstance method?

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-powershell

I'm trying to retrieve the instanceid, public dns name, and "Name" tag from the object returned by `get-ec2instance`.

```
$instances = foreach($i in (get-ec2instance)) '
{ $i.RunningInstance | Select-Object InstanceId, PublicDnsName, Tag }
```

Here's the output:

```
InstanceId                              PublicDnsName                     Tag
----------                              -------------                     ---
myInstanceIdHere                        myPublicDnsName                   {Name}
...                                     ...                               {Name}
```

I would like to be able to access `{Name}` using the line of code above and print its value in this output.  I've done a little bit of research since this initial posting, and found...

```
PS C:\Users\aneace\Documents> $instances[0].Tag.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     List`1                                   System.Object
```

Between this and the AWS docs, [I think Tag refers to this list](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/P_Amazon_EC2_Model_RunningInstance_Tag.htm), but I'm not certain.  I can access a table that prints key and value columns by calling `$instances[0].Tag`, but my problem now is that I would like that `Value` to be the output to my first table instead of the `{Name}` object.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the documentation, the `Tag` property is a **list** of `Tag` objects.  So in general, there will be multiple keys/values stored there.  Are you assuming that in your case there is only 1?

`Select-Object` allows you to grab not just raw property values, but calculated values as well.  Let's say you just want a comma-delimited list of the `Value`s from the `Tag` objects in the list. Here's how you would do it:

```
$instances = Get-EC2Instance `
             |%{ $_.RunningInstance } `
             | Select-Object InstanceId,PublicDnsName,@{Name='TagValues'; Expression={($_.Tag |%{ $_.Value }) -join ','}}
```

The elements of `$instances` will now have a property `TagValues` which is a string consisting of the `Value` from all Tags associated with the instance.

Comment: Really useful - I modified it slightly to report the tag key as well as value: `get-ec2instance |  %{$_.Instances} | select @{Name='TagValues'; Expression={($_.Tag | %{$_.Key
 + '=' + $_.Value}) -join ', '}}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to extract tags into a flat object along with other properties

```
$region = 'us-west-2'
$instances = (Get-Ec2Instance -Region $region).Instances | select `
    @{Name="ServerName";Expression={$_.tags | where key -eq "Name" | select Value -expand Value}},`
    InstanceType ,`
    InstanceId,`
    ImageId,`
    @{Name="Role";Expression={$_.tags | where key -eq "Role" | select Value -expand Value}},`
    @{Name="Group";Expression={$_.tags | where key -eq "Group" | select Value -expand Value}},`
    @{Name="Subsystem";Expression={$_.tags | where key -eq "subsystem" | select Value -expand Value}},`
    @{Name="State";Expression={$_.State.Name}},`
    @{Name="Region";Expression={$region}}

$instances | Sort-Object -Property State, ServerName | Format-Table
```